# Asp.Net Core 2.1 Localization

Tags: localization, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

i'm new to asp.net core trying to implement localization to support multiple language , my configuration is like this

```
 services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
            };
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        });
        services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,opts=> {opts.ResourcesPath="Resources"; })
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o=> {
            o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
            {
                return factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
            };
        });
```

this is the standard configuration and its working fine , i create a method inside a controller

```
 [Route("api/setlanguage")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SetLanguage (string culture)
    {

        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) });
        throw new Exception(_localizer["Hello",culture]);


    }
```

when i test with Postman like this : http://localhost:31563/api/SetLanguage?culture=en-US i'm getting a correct result but when i try to pass culture inside the body of request its not working , can anyone help me on this , thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make this work i just need to add

```
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
```

to force my currentThread.CurrentCulture/UICulture to take the culture value that i'm passing from body

```
 public IActionResult SetLanguage([FromBody] string culture)
     {          

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

       _localizer.WithCulture(new CultureInfo(culture));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Web API` parameter will get value from `query string` if you use like `(string culture)`.

If you want to get value from `Body`, you could add `[FromBody]` like below:

```
    public IActionResult SetLanguage([FromBody]string culture)
```

And then post your request like below:

[image]

Obviously, it will not work with `Query String` request if you add `[FromBody]`.

Comment: Yeah , but the localizer is not using my culture string that i'm passing on parameter  from body , is there a way to customize the localizer to use my body request ?

Comment: For built-in Localization middleware[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#localization-middleware],  it will not retrive culture setting in `Request body`, I think could implement your own culture prvoider[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-a-custom-provider] by getting "Culture" from body

Comment: I found out the issue here , i just need to pass the culture like you mentioned before and then i should force the change with Thread like this : 
`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);`

Comment: I think you could share us the complete solution and accept it as answer.